# More folders in raw folder

Tags: android

So guys, I have a lot of mini sounds in mys application, but it would be a lot easier if I could organize them in folders like \res\raw\foldername. I tried it but i can load only from R.raw and it shows only samples from "raw" folder. Any idea how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this with `raw`, but and alternative solution would be to put the files organized into directories, into `assets` folder, and then read from there.